# Is there a good (free) benchmarking tool for Windows platform?

Tags: web-applications, benchmarking, load-testing

Is there a good performance tool for benchmarking like [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home) for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one by Microsoft called the [Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313559).

Unfortunately the download link for it seems to be broken.

Ah, found it at download.com : http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Web-Application-Stress-Tool/3000-2196_4-14556.html?tag=mncol

It appears that the Team System versions of Visual Studio have support for load testing as well and may be intended to replace the Web Application Stress Tool.  That's the only reason I can think of for it not to be in Microsoft Downloads anymore.

Comment: Isn't so good... but solve...